# How does the CLR optimize boolean comparison operation under the hood?

Tags: .net, powershell, boolean, clr, compiler-optimization

###### NOTE: I'm using PowerShell for examples in this question, but the same applies to any .NET language.

In the .NET CLR, I'm curious to know how the different ways of evaluating boolean logic work under the hood.

- When considering practical applications and use-cases (even with *extremely* long running loops), the speed difference is so neglible that "it doesn't matter", which reduces boolean considerations to simply choosing a coding standard/format.
- "Which boolean comparison operator is faster?" isn't what this question is about.

Generally (I'm not asking for a comprehensive list of each modern CPU arhitecture's machine language instruction set), how does the .NET CLR "optimize" each of these boolean comparisons, and at the end of the day, is the CPU using different instructions to evaluate these seemingly identical comparisons?

- Evaluating for `== TRUE`:

  - `-eq $true` vs `-ne $false`
- Evaluating for `== FALSE`:

  - `(-not (<statement>))` vs `-eq $false` vs `-ne $true`
- ###### Pretend that each comparison is limited to (guaranteed) boolean results only, and we're ignoring $null for the sake of simple illustration.
- ###### Bonus points for historical context

Comment: If you want micro-optimized code then Powershell is absolutely the wrong tool for the job. You can see what C# would do using https://sharplab.io/ https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFBQMwAJboMLoN7LpHoBGA9mQDakDchxamALOgLIAUAlPvccQJYAzdiU68+PJBOmY4ATi50pMgL7i+QkegCEAXnSCAhpQDOAUzHLpBKzKJR5i9cTW3XKoA=== they are exactly the same.

Comment: `"Which boolean comparison operator is faster?" isn't what this question is about.` is included in the question.  This isn't about producing optimized code.  This is about "Does the CPU do anything different depending on the boolean comparison operator chosen, and how does the .NET CLR decide how to optimize if there is a difference?"  I'm not asking for advice on how to make something run faster.  I'm asking for technical insight into where machine language intersects with the .NET CLR solely related to boolean evaluation.

Comment: The .NET Common Language Runtime (CLR) is responsible for executing that operation under the hood. The CLR translates the PowerShell (or other .NET language) code into Intermediate Language (IL), which is then just-in-time (JIT) compiled into native machine code that can be executed by the CPU. Using tools like disassemblers or profilers would provide the most insight into how these operations are handled at the machine level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Charlieface](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14868997/charlieface) has provided the crucial pointer:

[sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/) is a great site that allows you to inspect what a given snippet of C# / F# / Visual Basic code compiles to in terms of [IL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language) (or JIT [ASM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_language))

Using it, you can observe the following, based on the following C# code:

```cs
public class C {
    bool b = false;
    int dummy = 0;
    public void M() {
        // equivalent positive tests
        if(b) { ++dummy; }
        if(b == true) { ++dummy; }
        if(b != false) { ++dummy; }
        // equivalent negative tests
        if(!b) { ++dummy; } 
        if(b == false) { ++dummy; }
        if(b != true) { ++dummy; }
    }
}
```

- The equivalent *positive* tests indeed compile to the *very same IL code* (in principle, abstracted below):

  ```
    ldarg.0
    ldfld bool C::b
    brfalse.s <target-statement>
  ```
- Likewise, the equivalent *negative* tests *all* compile to:

  ```
    ldarg.0
    ldfld bool C::b
    brtrue.s <target-statement>
  ```

As an aside: Note how the logic is *reversed*: testing for (effective) `true` results in a `brfalse.s` instruction, i.e. where to jump to if the test is *not* true, and vice versa (`brtrue.s`)

---

To experiment with the results yourself:

- Use [this link](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgPgAgzAAhgJgQYQQbwLACgEEIBGA9iRMQgLwIBmAhhAM4CmA3HoQmAHbAIATAK4BbEQE9qCAAwd8heEgAsCALIAKAJRZOXQgHp9CFgEchYAG6MWfBAAcSTMMEssEwFk2BNde7rXUibUwEAGpQ4TFxNgQAX189MACiahpgACchFmCwiNEJGPj5PyTAhABCGgZmbKxcyIK4hK5DYzNLa1seFgBzehcLNw8vH2LEgPKguvCG6LiEZsJSlKoqxlYcmfy5or8CZYq0zNqQrajChKKioA==).
- Via the `Results` dropdown list in the pane to the right, you can also ask for your input code to be *decompiled to C#* (irrespective of the original input language), which corroborates the above findings:

  - The equivalent *positive* tests *all* decompile to:

    ```
    if (b) ...
    ```
  - The equivalent *negative* tests *all* decompile to:

    ```
    if (!b) ...
    ```